# Task done in python automation

Tags: python, selenium, automation

Like the title says I am working on a little project where I need to
"open link, click on a button, replace a part of the link and do the task again"

My code is a little messy and I am still a newbie, but this is it so far, and the problem I am running into is that the page doesn't open when I add the 'if else' function. The page just doesn't open, I could do without the if else, but since the button's xpath changes in random numbered pages that's the only solution I can think of

```
PATH = Service("C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=PATH)
driver.maximize_window()

button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div[1]/main/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div/section/div[2]/div[3]/div/div[2]/button")
button1 = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div[1]/main/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div/section/div/div[3]/div/button")

for i in range(1,5):
    print(f"https://test.com/page/{i}")
    driver.get(f"https://test.com/page/{i}")
    if button is not None:
        button.click()
    else:
        button1.click()
```

Comment: You try to get button before load website. Do .get() then .find_element and then you can check if button. Also that xpaths are "bad" use class or some attributes to identify elements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Load the page before getting the buttons. Also, make sure the button is loaded with this script:

```py
PATH = Service("C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=PATH)
driver.maximize_window()

button_selector = "/html/body/div[1]/div[1]/main/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div/section/div[2]/div[3]/div/div[2]/button"
button1_selector = "/html/body/div[1]/div[1]/main/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div/section/div/div[3]/div/button"

for i in range(1, 5):
    print(f"https://test.com/page/{i}")

    # Load the page
    driver.get(f"https://test.com/page/{i}")

    # Get the buttons
    button = driver.find_element_by_xpath(button_selector) or None
    button1 = driver.find_element_by_xpath(button1_selector) or None
    time.sleep(1)  # Make sure the buttons are loaded

    if button is not None:
        button.click()
    elif button1 is not None:
        button1.click()


driver.quit() # Be sure to close the driver
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply Martin, I tried this code and now at least the page loads up but for some reason it stops there, doesn't click the button.
I did try to change the "time.sleep" to 5-7 incase the buttons weren't loading fully, but it still doesn't work

Comment: Are you sure the selectors are right? Don't the buttons have a class or ID that can make them more uniquely accessible?